# How would I recreate a binary tree from its inorder and postorder values?

Tags: java, binary-tree, tree-traversal, inorder, postorder

```
Inorder: 3 2 1 5 4 6 8 9 7 11 10
Postorder: 1 2 3 4 5 6 9 11 10 7 8
```

I believe I am on the right track by taking the last postorder value as the root, finding that value in the Inorder list and splitting the tree to the left and the right of that value. From what I've been trying, I was able to come up with this result: It was not formatting correctly so I screenshot it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Get the last element from the Postorder, this is your root element, then find that element in the Inorder and split the elements in left and right list giving you LEFT: "3 2 1 5 4 6" and RIGHT: "9 7 11 10" then walk the Postorder list and split it once you find the first number before the index of the root element in the Inorder list, in this case this is "6" so walk till 6 and this will give you "1 2 3 4 5 6" and the rest is "9 11 10 7". Then insert those lists in reverse order, e.g.: "6 5 4 3 2 1" and after that "7 10 11 9" this should give you the correct order of the tree.

Answer (score 0):

It is a little tricky, maybe because contradicts a little the brain hemispheres ;-)

The parameters of interest are:

- `post`: an array containing the postorder traversal
- `lp`: left index of `post` array
- `rp`: right index of `post` array
- `in`: an array containing the inorder traversal
- `li`: left index of `in` array
- `ri`: riggh index of `ìn` array

The procedure is "naturally" recursive. At each recursion, the root always is `post[rp]`. That is the last visited node (in postorder).

So, the first thing to do is to know the index of the root in the array `in`. In order to compute that, we scan from `li` to `ri` and we search `post[rp]`. Let `i` the index of root in the array `in`. **I assume that the tree does not have duplicated keys**.

Given the index of root, then

1. `i - li` is the number of nodes in the left subtree
2. `ri - i` is the number of nodes in the right subtree

Now, `in` becomes naturally partitioned. The left subtree is between `[li, i - 1]` and the right subtree is between `[i + 1, ri]`.

What I think is a little confuse is to determine where are the subtrees in `post`. The left subtree is between `[lp, lp + (i - li) - 1]` and the right is between `[rp - (ri - i), rp - 1]`. Take in account the numbers of nodes of each subtree expressed above (in the enumerated list).

With this knowledge we would be ready for designing an algorithm (I write in pseudo-C++, but I think it is very easy to translate to java):

```
Node * build_postorder(const vector<int> & post, long lp, long rp,
                       const vector<int> & in, long li, long ri)
{
  if (lp > rp)
    return nullptr; // we stop recursion when the tree is empty

  Node * root = new Node(post[rp]); // Creates the root with key value post[rp]

  int i = li;
  for (; i <= ri; ++i) // search in inorder array the index of root
    if (in[i] == post[rp])
      break; // this line must always to execute it (if everything is oK)

  LLINK(root) = build_postorder(post, lp, lp + (i - li) - 1, in, li, i - 1);
  RLINK(root) = build_postorder(post, rp - (ri - i), rp - 1, in, i + 1, ri);

  return root;
}
```

Good luck!